false fontsize with remcalc function in foundation zurb
I would like to use rem and not px as the unit of measurement for the website. The problem is that the calculated values are not correct.
I'm using:

foundation zurb
version 6.8.1
foundation-sites-template@1.1.1 start

For example, my script looks like this:
h1 {
 font-size: rem-calc(30px)
}

The following is generated as the result in the CSS:
h1 {
 font-size: 1.3636363636rem;
}

Does anyone have any advice on what is wrong here and how I can correct it?
Best regards and many thanks for your help
m.orange
